# Icefaces Performance Issues - Partial Submit

Tags: java, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-3

I have a JSF Site, displaying a HTML-Table. I have 14 Columns for next two weeks and some users for the rows. The users depends on a selected option from a selectonemenu.

So whats the problem? If I load for example 50 user for 2 weeks, i have a big filled table. After that every action listener on any link on this site takes years before the response is there. Then I created an action listener which does nothing! This action take years too! If i only load 5 users into my table, the action which does nothing is really fast!

So my Question: What is Icefaces doing? Why does I have so long times just performing an small action in the backend? It`s not the Method in the backend bean which is slow.

UPDATE:

I wrote some sample Code, where you can nicely see my problem. If I take 50 columns and 300 rows, the site takes ca 15 sec for loading. Clicking the button do nothing then will always take ca 15 seconds. If I only load 5 columns and 5 rows, the do nothing button is fast!

[JSF Site Code](http://pastebin.com/cHFZv3Ca)
[Managed Bean Code](http://pastebin.com/tMa3GNEQ)

Comment: it`s not possible. i try to build some sample!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't share the code i can only say debug that code! see what steps are extra slow or witch line are useless, called more times then needed, or if you go through the entire data when not needed. finally, maybe change the data structure, use hash table or something else in order to search the data faster

Comment: I am loading a lot of data. These data is iterated by ui:repeat and displayed by an own html table (not icefaces). After every request (by an action listener or so) these table seems to load the data again and I don`t know why.. All my methods are debugged and performance is okay. Can I tell my Button only to execute the method and only to render only one special gui element?

Comment: @Nils well, i'm not an expert on theese issues, but now that you have the datails u can issue a more specific question. first search it in google. i think this issue is answered...